# nvim "failed to run config for nvim-dap", loader.lua:369 attemp to call field 'setup' (a nil value)

Tags: debugging, lua, configuration, neovim

I am getting the following error when I startup nvim, not sure why?

"**nvim "failed to run config for nvim-dap", loader.lua:369 attemp to call field 'setup' (a nil value)**"

I started off using lazyvim, and my lua config has the following entry

```lua
{ "mfussenegger/nvim-dap" },
```

I managed to setup JS/TypeScript debugging and it seems to be working fine. I just want this startup error message fix.

[image: NeoVIM nvim-dap error]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `nvim-dap` is trying to call the field `config`, but it's not defined. Worked for me to just add an empty function for this `config` field.

```lua
{
  "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
  config = function() end,
},
```