Failed to run `config` for nvim-dap
I was trying to install java plugin to LazyVim and gave me the following error:
Failed to run `config` for nvim-dap

...local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim/lua/lazy/core/loader.lua:373: attempt to call field 'setup' (a nil value)

# stacktrace:
  - ~/.config/nvim/lua/config/lazy.lua:9
  - ~/.config/nvim/init.lua:2

here it is a screenshot
I searched solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77575033/25088612, but I don't know where to apply this solution.

I had the same issue. I keep my java related plugins in ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/java-lombok.lua, just added the piece of code there:
return {
  ...,
  {
    "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
    config = function() end,
  },
}

You can find the whole configuration here https://gitlab.com/bosacky/nvim/-/blob/lazyvim/lua/plugins/java-lombok.lua?ref_type=heads#L37
